# Is it possible to highlight text in a Win32 edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) program in which I load text files. Would it be possible to highlight a particular word that is being displayed in the edit box?

By highlight, I mean, something like changing the color of the text as in syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard Edit control does not support that. Use a RichEdit control instead. It supports applying font/color settings to a range of characters via the `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` message.

Comment: Thanks. What about creating a custom edit control? I'm not going to do it for this project, but I'm curious about it. I can't seem to find any tutorial for that. Could you point me to one? like one that outlines the basic steps and format?

Answer (score 2):

The [Iczelion tutorial](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tut35.html) shows an alternative way to `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` that seems more like what you are asking. There are a few other ones. It was more common back when computers were slower, but just-in-time highlighting is the way to go.

Comment: The pitfalls of `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` described in that tutorial can be overcome without resorting to subclassing `WM_PAINT`. See this article: http://www.bellsouthpwp2.net/r/e/rediv/Papers/FasterSyntaxHighlighting.doc

Comment: Is there a source that isn't a Word document (html/rtf/pdf) ? I haven't had to do syntax highlighting in a long time and would like to check it out.

Comment: found original source [C++ builder developer's journal October 1999](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm)

Comment: the link is broken now

Comment: Once again, a link-only answer becomes useless due to an off-site resource that no longer is. If it wasn't for the helpful comments I'd flag this as *not an answer*. Instead, I'm going to have to spent **my** reputation to vote on it. (Anyway, here's a [snapshot from 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120426055125/http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut35.html) of the original content, I guess. Plus, a [live version](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tut35.html), too.)