# WinAPI: Draw rectangles behind Edit Control text

Tags: c, winapi

I have a read-only Edit Control that displays a multiline string. I set the background color for it using `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in the window procedure of the dialog that my control is subclassed from. If the window is shrunk, scrolllbar appears for the Edit Control. It all works fine, you can select, copy, scroll the text left and right.

```
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_DEBUGGER_DISASSEMBLY))
        {
            SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
        }
        break;
```

I want to make custom background color behind a particular line. My normal BG is white there, and for that line I want, say, blue.

I tried using `WM_PAINT` for the Edit Control, but then I seem to have to draw the text once again, or the original text of the control won't be visible until I select it. And if I manually draw text too, it won't scroll the same as the original text.

Comment: As this seems to be line oriented use a list control instead?

Comment: I would have, if it was created by me originally. Here I have to tweak an existing control, with lots of logic already relying on it being Edit.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8024157/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have an edit control, then I don't see a solution.  However, with some tweaking, you might be able to use a rich edit control.  It accepts most of the same messages as an edit control. The trick would be using SetCharFormat to set the format of the line you want to change.

Comment: I'm already trying switching to it, and it doesn't have the the usual context menu Edit Control has: Copy, Paste, Select All, etc. I'm currently attempting to generate my own menu for it. Is there an easy way to make it display the standard edit text menu, or I have to manually create it?

Comment: I think you have to roll your own handler and menu.

Comment: After moving to RichEdit entirely, I found out it **can not** set specific colors to arbitrary line's BG without the exact same hackery I'm having with Edit Control. You either have to select it, or have a caret on it, or draw your text on top of its own. http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tut35.html

Comment: You can get the selection using EM_GETSEL.  Save the values.  Use EM_SETSEL to select the desired line.  Use EM_SETCHARFORMAT to set the color for the line.  Call EM_SETSEL with the saved selection values.

Comment: This article helped a lot to overcome some richedit limitations http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm

Comment: Since I can't edit the comment, here's an archived link for posterity: https://web.archive.org/web/20170802220644/http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm